# How to fade in the entire UIButton instead of just title when tapped?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

So I have the following button, when tapped only adds fade animation to the title. I want the fade animation to happen in the entire button. How can I do that? Thanks!

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setTitle("Btn", for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
    button.tintColor = .white
    
    view.addSubview(button)
    
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60.0),
      button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60.0),
      button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
      button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
    ])
  }
}
```

Comment: add simple fade in animation on button action.

Comment: Oh so the button's fade animation is not in-built? @RTXGamer

Comment: yes only text portion blinks, you can use `showsTouchWhenHighlighted` to get the glow effect on touch.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using addTarget with a objc func:

```
@objc func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton){
    print("buttonTapped")
     sender.alpha = 0.5
     DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) {
         sender.alpha = 1.0
     }
}
```

Execute it via:

```
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
```